# Conditional based display data in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
[{
    "first": 1,
    "second": 1,
    "third": "deep",
    "object": ["abc", "def"]
  },
  {
    "first": 1,
    "second": 1,
    "third": "deeper",
    "object": ["ghi", "jkl"]
  }, {
    "first": 1,
    "second": 1,
    "third": "deep",
    "object": ["mno", "pqr"]
  }, {
    "first": 1,
    "second": 1,
    "third": "deeper",
    "object": ["stuv", "wxyz"]
  }
]
```

This is a json file I have, My need is,

I displayed data in my dropdown using ng-repeat. But, I can't able to display data based on the condition.

I have two buttons, the first name is "deep" and the second name is "deeper".

I want to display data based on this.

If I click the "deep" button, I want to show only deep data, same as "deeper".

How can I handle this in angularjs?

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <div class="dropdown-item" ng-repeat="filter in filters">
      <div class="filter-class">{{filter}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-if property. For more details check https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-if.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-if in this way

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.filters = [{
      "first": 1,
      "second": 1,
      "third": "deep",
      "object": ["abc", "def"]
    },
    {
      "first": 1,
      "second": 1,
      "third": "deeper",
      "object": ["ghi", "jkl"]
    }, {
      "first": 1,
      "second": 1,
      "third": "deep",
      "object": ["mno", "pqr"]
    }, {
      "first": 1,
      "second": 1,
      "third": "deeper",
      "object": ["stuv", "wxyz"]
    }
  ];

}])
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <div class="dropdown-item" ng-repeat="filter in filters">
        <div ng-if="filter.third =='deep' " class="filter-class">{{filter}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your view by adding the `ng-if` directive to handle the condition.

```
<div class="dropdown-item" ng-repeat="filter in filters" ng-if="filter.third == appliedCheck">
    <div class="filter-class">{{filter}}</div>
</div>
```

Add the ng-click to hold the value of `appliedCheck`:

```
<button ng-click="appliedCheck = 'deep'">Deep</button>
<button ng-click="appliedCheck = 'deeper'">Deeper</button>
```

Hope that helps!